# Train Logical Question

Tags: logic

A city train travels on double circle rails having a main station and stations 1 – 8 in this order.
There are two trains: Train A and train B. Train A travels clockwise and stops only at odd
numbered stations and the main station. Train B travels counterclockwise and stops only at
even numbered stations and the main station. Only at the main station the travelers can switch
one train for another.

[image: Stations Image]

Michael travels from station 5 to station 6, Sarah from station 7 to station 4, and Liza from
station 2 to station 5.
a) How many times do they totally travel between stations 5 to 6?
b) Which station of 1 to 8 is passed maximum number of times? How many times?
“Passed” means that the train passes a station without stopping or the traveler doesn´t get out
of the train even though the train stops

**P.S: I am preparing for my entrance exam and I found this question on my sample paper and have no clue how to verify my answer. This is what I have tried and my answers are:**

**1) four**

**2) three times on station 8 not 7.**

**Updated**

*Micheal travels: 5-7-Station A-8-6

Sarah: 7-Station A-8-6-4

Liza:2-4-6-8-Station B-1-3-5*

Comment: It would help if you posted what you have tried, not just magic numbers.  Then we can check your reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first answer is correct, but the train passes station $8$ *four* times, twice for each of the first two passengers and zero times for the last, and $8$ is the only station passed more than $3$ times making it the solution.

Checking problems like this is very hard. The best way to do it on your own is to make a chart and count carefully and double check your work. However, this recommendation basically accounts to "do the problem correctly." The best way to check work for a problem like this is for someone else to check your work for you.

If you explain how you arrived at your answers I can tell you where the faulty reasoning is for $b$ and hopefully confirm that your reasoning is correct for $a$.

Comment: Thank you so much Stella. Please refer to my explanation above and correct me for question 2) I have updated my answer

Comment: @alexbliss I think you misread the question: “Passed” means that the **train passes a station without stopping** or the traveler doesn´t get out of the train even though the train stops. Therefore the list of stations Michael passes is $5-6-7-8-A-8-7-6$

Comment: can you please explain for liza and sarah? I am so much grateful to you : )

Comment: Liz is $2-1-S-1-2-3-4-5$ because she gets on the even train first and so is going in the opposite direction. Sarah is $7-8-S-8-7-6-5-4$ because they get on the odd train first and so go in the same direction as Michael.